# Overcome with Read lock or Write Lock List in Excel filepath in SSIS

Tags: ssis

[image: Read lock list error]

I got the read/write lock list error on excel file path. Is there a way in SSIS to overcome this error?

Comment: what's the component/task producing the error?

Comment: I am using it for Foreach loop Container where you check the files and loop the files giving fileExtension. I was getting that the excel file path was getting this read list and write lock list error.

Comment: it's that variable used only in the Variable Mapping of the foreach container or is it also used as part of an expression?

Comment: The filepath is a variable that is used in expression as well.

Comment: That could be the problem then. If it's used as the return variable of the foreach loop (i.e. it's listed in the Variable Mapping tab), then it can't be used in a expression to set a property of the same foreach container.